# ASM diskgroup drop from another ASM instance

Tags: oracle, oracle-asm

I have created long time back one ASM RAC setup and I created one diskgroup with some name say `xyz`. I think that instance is gone but the diskgroup was not dropped exclusively using command:

```
drop diskgroup xyz including contents;
```

Now that I have created a new setup and want to re utilize these disks, I am getting below error:

```
CREATE DISKGROUP XYZ EXTERNAL REDUNDANCY DISK ...

ORA-15003: diskgroup "xyz" already mounted in another lock name space
```

How can this diskgroup be removed? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you still interested?

Comment: Why can't you drop it now?

Answer (score 1):

Check the `diskgroup` status in both instances.  If it is showing mounted in both instances then:

1. `dismount` the diskgroup in all the instance except one.  For instance, if you have a 3 node RAC setup, then dismount the diskgroup in nodes 2 and 3.
2. `Drop` the diskgroup from the  1st node.